# Evaluating multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

If it exists, find the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}-1}.$$

I tried the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x^3-y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}-1} = \frac{x^3-y^4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}-1}\frac{{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}+1}}{{\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}+1}}\\\\=\frac{(x^3-y^4)\big({\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}+1}\big)}{x^2+y^4}\end{align*}$$
At this point I'm not sure how to proceed. Some hint would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate it for the two directions $(0,y)$ and $(x,0)$. The limit is not exists.

Comment: Great, we get $-2$ and $0$. How did you know to try this? Is there some way of seeing that this is a good thing to try? I'm trying to get a better feel for multivariable limit problems.

Comment: @rehband You have $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}(\sqrt{x^2+y^4+1}+1)=2$, so it's left to "find" limit of the rest of your formula.